# Why don't changes to my Collections persist to the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

EnitityFramework handles many-to-many ( * : * ) with `Collection`s in the model. So, I have a `SupportEvent` and `Employee` tables with ( * : * ) relationship and collections in each. I'm needing to add employees to a support event on a Razor page.

Originally, I was doing it in a not-so-elegant way by passing data separately through the form. When the `Edit(SupportEvent)` method was called the changes made to the `Employees` collection were present. However, when I called `SaveChanges(supportEvent)` the changes were not persisted to the db.

After looking around I found ViewModels are the way to properly handle this so I followed [MVC 5, Entity Framework 6 and Many to Many Relationship : a step by step View Model approach](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/702890/MVC-Entity-Framework-and-Many-to-Many-Relation).

The immediate "problem" I found was, although this way may be more in line with the pattern, when I entered the `Edit()` method the `supportEvent` was exactly the same and the result of `SaveChanges()` was too. Names and typos aside, I can't see anywhere my code differs in a meaningful way.

Here's my code:

```
// ViewModel
public class SupportEventViewModel
{
    public SupportEvent SupportEvent { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllEmployees { get; set; }

    private List<int> selectedEmployees;
    public List<int> SelectedEmployees
    {
        get 
        {
            if (selectedEmployees == null)
            {
                selectedEmployees = SupportEvent
                    .Employees
                    .Select(m => m.Id)
                    .ToList();
            }
            return selectedEmployees;
        }
        set { selectedEmployees = value; }
    }
}
```

And the Edit():

```
    // SupportEventController - Edit()
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(SupportEventViewModel model, bool? active)
    {
        foreach(var e in model.SelectedEmployees) 
        {
            model.SupportEvent.Employees
                .Add(db.Employees.Find(e));
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(model.SupportEvent).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction(((bool)active) ? 
                "ActiveTicketDetails" : "Details", "Ticket", new { id = model.SupportEvent.TicketId });
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

And the partial edit view:

```
// The partial view/form
@model ProjectWhiteWave.ViewModels.SupportEventViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SupportEvent</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SupportEvent.SupportEventId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupportEvent.DateOpened, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupportEvent.DateOpened)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupportEvent.DateOpened)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupportEvent.DateClosed, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupportEvent.DateClosed)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupportEvent.DateClosed)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AllEmployees, "Technicians", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedEmployees, Model.AllEmployees)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupportEvent.Description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupportEvent.Description)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupportEvent.Description)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything seems to be correct, and I think that's verified by the fact the changes I make in the view end up in the edit method. I know it's not being saved because when `Edit` redirects and I return to the details page there's no changes present.

What am I missing/doing wrong that prevents the data to be saved to the database?

Answer (score 0):

i think that this line:

```
model.SupportEvent.Employees.Add(db.Employees.Find(e));
```

should be replaced with this line:

```
model.SupportEvent.Employees.Add(db.Employees.Find(emp => emp.Id = e));
```

since **e** is actually the **id** of a specific employee (that is the meaning of **Select(m => m.Id)** on SelectedEmployees)

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it. Although, e it is the Id, find finds it based on that. When Save is called the employees have been added to the local instance, the ModelState is valid, but nothing gets written.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're saying is that an employee can have multiple support events, and support events can have multiple employees? There is no way to map this relationship without a junction table in the middle.  You need to tell EF to create a junction table based on this relationship.

If you've already done this then just ignore the previous statement, but look at the following code to see how I set up simple many to many relationships and see if that helps.

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SupportEvent> SupportEvents { get; set; }
}

public class SupportEvent
{
    [key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

// DbContext
public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
public DbSet<SupportEvent> SupportEvents { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

     modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
          .HasMany(x => x.SupportEvents)
          .WithMany(x => x.Employees)
          .Map(m => 
           {
               m.ToTable("EmployeeSupportEvents");
               m.MapLeftKey("EmployeeId");
               m.MapRightKey("SupportEventId");
           }
}
```

now adding or removing events from employees of vice verse is super easy.

```
var event = db.SupportEvents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "whatever");
var employee = db.Employee.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id = "blah");
if(event == null || employee == null) return NotFound();

event.Employees.Add(employee);
// OR
employee.SupportEvents.Add(event);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. So, I've seen this approach while looking for solutions. I started this project with Model First; when I run the project with breakpoints set in the model builder, none get hit. Do you know the way to get it called and if that will break my work flow.

Comment: How are you injecting your DbContext into your controller? it should call this method when it's instantiated.  In my case that's when the controller instance is created via Unity DI.  Are you making sure to use a new instance per call?

Comment: The controllers are auto generated. Inside the controller it creates a single db context. That's not the way it should be? I'm passing a view model into the controller from the form as above.

Comment: yeah, but it's creating a new one right? it's not referencing a static instance or singleton? I would remove the auto generated one for now and create it inside the action to see if it's being created properly. Then try and read some existing data out, this will let you know if your context is okay (or has read access at least).  Then try and add a single entity and save, then check your relationships.

Comment: I'll have to spend some time on changing I guess. It quickly complains about referencing multiple instances of an IEntityTracker with the new db context. It's still not being called either way and I don't think any changes in that regard will matter. In the method, prior to adding your changes, it contained `throw new UnintendedCodeFirstException`. I think I'll track down how to fix it and do that in reverse. Thanks.